# C# Basic Authentication from curl request

Tags: c#, authentication, curl, basic-authentication

I have curl request and i'd like create analog to C#. Bat all my attempts have failed. I tried everything I could find in google. This description API https://github.com/onlinerby/onliner-b2b-api/blob/master/docs/oauth20.md

this curl

```
$process = curl_init("https://b2bapi.onliner.by/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "204da9b95e2480a3455f:7a4bbb61262fdf41d410645292a0489ba752c6b9");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials'));
$result = curl_exec($process);
curl_close($process);`
```

this my c# code

```
string url = "https://b2bapi.onliner.by/oauth/token";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("204da9b95e2480a3455f:7a4bbb61262fdf41d410645292a0489ba752c6b9"));
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
var result = client.UploadString(url, "grant_type=client_credentials");`
```

please help me, i am lost a lot time ...

Comment: You're sending a Basic authorization header, but the request is using OAuth, not Basic. [Here's an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx) from MSDN that may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but this method not help me... I guess i need to write in support may they help me.

Comment: I tried library LibCurlNet, but she didnt help me, or i couldnt use... Iwrite in support and  wait answer.